# Dialog box doesn't appear when EXIT button is clicked

Tags: android, eclipse

I have added a dialog box to appear whenever I want the app to quit which appears when I press the exit button.There is no error shown but the exit button is no displaying the dialog box when I click it.Can Someone help?

```
public void addListenerOnButton2()
{ 

    exit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
    exit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(
        MainActivity.this);
 alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("EXIT?");
 alertDialogBuilder
 .setMessage("Click yes to exit!")
 .setCancelable(false)
 .setPositiveButton("Yes",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener(){
     public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
         String exme = "Ok button Pressed";
 Toast t = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,exme, 
         Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); 
 t.show();
 MainActivity.this.finish();
     }
   })
   .setNegativeButton("No",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int id) {
            String exme1="Cancel button Pressed";
    Toast t1 = Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,exme1, 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT); 
    t1.show();
    dialog.cancel();
        }
    });
 AlertDialog alertDialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
 alertDialog.show();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Please don't put exit buttons in Android apps.  It's "anti pattern", bad usability and not required.  Remove the exit button, throw away this code and move on to the next, more important, problem.

Comment: Is it going to exit button click listener??

Answer (score 0):

```
Button exitButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
exitButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view)
    {
        new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
        .setMessage("Click yes to exit!")
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Ok button Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Cancel button Pressed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        })
        .show();
    }
});
```